# How can I display the "open with" dialog for an unregistered file extension?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I want to let the user select an association (open with) for an currently unregistered file extension.

Currently I'm telling the API to open the file by using `ShellExecute` and it returns an `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION` error code.

Is there a way to tell the API that it should let the user select a new association?

Comment: this might do it: `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL "C:\Path\TEXT.TXT"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use

```
procedure ShellOpenAs(const AFileName: string; AHandle: HWND);
begin
  ShellExecute(AHandle, 'open', PChar('rundll32.exe'), PChar('shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL ' + AFileName), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

**Edit** (inspired by David's comment and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13229516/1431618):
One can omit `ShellExecute` and `RunDll32` by calling `OpenAs_RunDLL` directly:

```
procedure OpenAs_RunDLL(hwnd: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: LPSTR; nCmdShow: Integer); stdcall; external shell32;

procedure ShellOpenAs(AHandle: HWND; const AFileName: string);
begin
  OpenAs_RunDLL(AHandle, HInstance, PChar(AFileName), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

There is also [SHOpenWithDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows Vista and later. (I find it interesting that Microsoft wrote a RunDLL compatible entry point but until Vista didn't bother to provide a regular API function.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll add this as the fallback if the first fails, since I only want the dialog if I can't already open it.

Comment: The correct way to invoke the dialog is to use the `openas` verb instead: `ShellExecute(AHandle, 'openas', PChar(AFileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL); `

Comment: @Remy: This doesn't work for me (Windows 7 64-bit). I get system error 1155 - translated from German: "The specified file has no associated application".

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt: `openas` works for me on my Win7 64-bit machine, both for `ShellExecute()` and `ShellExecuteEx()`.

Comment: Would be easier to call `OpenAs_RunDLL` directly rather than involving a call to `ShellExecute`.

Comment: Note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is undocumented and [does not always work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566667/rundll32-shell32-dll)

Answer (score 4):

Go with following code you will get your solution-

```
public const uint SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST = 12;//add this line in your code


CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED|COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
sei.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
sei.lpVerb = "openas";
sei.lpFile = "C:\\yourfile.ext";
sei.lfmask= SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;//add this line in your code
ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
```

SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST this variable set "Verb" from presented system registry.

Comment: This is the correct answer for my scenario (not necessarily the same as the OP), which is to show the "Select an app to open.." dialog, in this case on Windows 11.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do not use explicit verb. Using a specific verb like 'open' is a big mistake:

- 'open' may be not a default verb (for example, it may be 'play', 'edit' or 'run')
- 'open' may not exists

It is a way more correct to **simply pass nil as verb**. The system will automatically select most appropriate verb:

- Default verb will be used, if it is set
- 'open' verb will be used, if no default verb is set
- first verb will be used, if no default and 'open' verbs are available
- **if no verbs are assigned - the system will bring "Open with" dialog**

In other words, simple

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'C:\MyFile.StrangeExt', ...);
```

will show "Open with" dialog.

Only use a **specific** verb if you want a **specific** action. E.g. 'print', 'explore', 'runas'. Otherwise - just pass nil.