# How popup "Connect To" dialog?

Tags: delphi, winapi

[image]

how to popup this form use delphi ?
is `ShellExecuteEx` or `ShellExecute`  can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line you can do this. (at least, on Win7 for me...()

```
 rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN
```

So, just wrap that in a suitable `ShellExecute` or similar call.

Note that the dialog is designed to pop up in the system tray. I don't know how you'd get it to appear somewhere more obvious.

Also, have a look at this thread. There's another way mentioned here that describes how to do it in a possibly more useful fashion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.development.device.drivers/nPn-PH3g_2Q

---

If you want to invoke this from your program, it's simpler just to skip the `rundll32` call. You can load the DLL yourself and invoke the function. For example:

```
procedure RunVANW(hwnd: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: LPSTR; 
    nCmdShow: Integer); stdcall; external 'van.dll';

procedure ShowViewAvailableNetworksDialog;
begin
  RunVANW(0, 0, nil, 0);
end;
```

I would expect that this functionality is not available on older versions of Windows, and almost certainly will be modified on future versions of Windows. So you may prefer to write the DLL import using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, and switch behaviour at runtime depending on whether or not the `RunVANW` function is available.

Comment: +1 Very well played sir! The easiest way to do it in code is to call `LoadLibrary` to load `van.dll`, `GetProcAddress` to get `RunVAN` function pointer, and then call `RunVAN`. Rather heavy duty to invoke `rundll32` or `ShellExecute` from code. It looks like you need to load `RunVANW`. This does look like an unsupported hack though. I suspect it won't work on all versions of Windows.

Comment: Or even just like this: `procedure RunVANW; stdcall; external 'van.dll';`

Comment: @David: The last one crashes - apparently the signature has to be RunDll-compatible: `procedure RunVANW(hwnd: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: LPSTR; nCmdShow: Integer); stdcall; external 'van.dll';`. Then calling `RunVANW(Handle, HInstance, '', 0);` works (for me :-)).

Comment: @UliGerhardt Ah, you are right. My mistake. Didn't crash for me when I did it wrong, but I guess I just got lucky! Or unlucky depending on your point of view!

Comment: @UliGerhardt and David - I'm at the edge of my comfort zone here, so feel free to write a better answer incorporating your comments and the  initial concept. I'll gladly upvote ;-)

Comment: @Roddy I added some code to your answer. We don't need another answer here in my view.

Comment: @UliGerhardt I didn't do anything special. Blocks with 4 space indentation are code blocks and display pre-formatted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found it doesn't work in windows 8. error : "Access violation at address 76359B51 in module 'combase.dll'. Read of address 55C08BC3 "

Comment: @ONion that's exactly as I expected. It is, after all, an undocumented hack!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's OK to use `procedure RunVANW; stdcall; external 'van.dll';`  use `procedure RunVANW(hwnd: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: LPSTR;
  nCmdShow: Integer); stdcall; external 'van.dll';` will got a error in win8

Comment: @DavidHeffernan by the way, There are other ways to do this?

Comment: @ONion Perhaps. Not that I know of though.